# Powershell script Memory usage

Tags: powershell, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I'm running a simple script to get all inactive users (enabled state) not logged in for 60 days as below. The script seems to work fine on my workstation with ARS 6.7 & WinXP . But if i run the same script on another workstation with ARS 6.9 & Win7 the RAM usage of the script goes on increasing over time & it finally throws OutofMemory exception (after reaching 1.5+ GB) & aborts. The same script when run on WinXP workstation (ARS v6.7) does not consume more than 50 MB of RAM throughout. The domain i'm scanning is pretty big with over 550000 accounts. I'm totally confused about the issue here...Pls help!

```
[datetime]$TodayDate = Get-Date
[datetime]$InActivityDate = $TodayDate.AddDays(-62).Date

try
{
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $SearchOU -Service $Service -SizeLimit $SizeLimit -PageSize 1000 -Enabled -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties SamAccountName,`
Name,ParentContainer,DN,LastLogon,WhenCreated,PasswordLastSet,employeeID,`
employeeNumber,Manager,AccountIsDisabled,co,scriptPath |`

#Filter out inactive accounts
Where-Object {$_.LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $InActivityDate} |`

Select-Object SamAccountName,Name,ParentContainer,DN,LastLogon,WhenCreated,`
PasswordLastSet,employeeID,employeeNumber,Manager,`
AccountIsDisabled,co,scriptPath | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
}

catch
{
$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
$ErrTime = Get-Date
Write-Host "Error occured:`n$ErrorMessage" -ForegroundColor Red
Write-Output "[$ErrTime] Error occured:`n$ErrorMessage" | Out-File $OutputFile -Append

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should delegate filtering to AD side, quoting from `Get-ADUser` help: `Get-ADUser -filter { lastLogon -le $logonDate }` In your case, `Get-QADUser` cannot delegate filtering, so swap to Microsoft's AD module: `Get-ADUser -filter { lastLogon -le $InactivityDate }`. To get the module, install RSAT for oyur Windows version, then (if not enabled by default) go "Add/remove Windows components - RSAT - Role administration services - AD/LDAP - Windows Powershell module" and enable it.

Comment: thx for the reply Vesper. unfortunately i do NOT have local admin rights & core powershell is not packaged. I'll try convincing my local sys admin for this ;)

Comment: You'll likely get an approve, because AD module does not require anything other than a domain account to retrieve data. And anyway, you'll likely need to do more monitoring than just AD, so having a RSAT ready will do good to both you and your sysadmin.

Comment: understood, let me get back to you. Thx again! =)

Comment: Unfortunately i've been asked to stick to QAD cmdlets. Strange thing is this happens to even the simplest scripts, for eg. getting user details scripts - this script would read from a input file get user details & write to a output file,if i input large users (8000+) then even this script throws OutOfMemory Exception, while works smoothly on a WinXP workstation with ARS v6.7? I dnt seem to understand the issue here...is it the OS or the ARS version? Pls help!

Comment: This seems to be ARS version, [see here](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/iam/f/4817/t/19560157) for a similar problem. Apparently holding more than a single `QADObject` in memory with a newer library version holds too much memory for the script to process a lot of them. I think this is a bug in ARS Powershell module, consider contacting Dell for fix. Also, are there any arguments from your sysadmin to stick qith QAD, if you can prove to him that the latest version is bugged?

Answer (score 0):

Launching the Quest Shell in **MTA** mode has solved this problem. This can simply be done by adding "-mta" parameter to existing shortcut.

eg.

> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>   -psconsolefile "C:\Program Files\Quest Software\Management Shell for AD\ConsoleSettings.psc1" -noexit **-Mta** -command ". 'C:\Program
>   Files\Quest Software\Management Shell for AD\qsft.ps1'"